# Why does JS say "class cannot be called as a function" in this case?

Tags: javascript

I have stumbled upon a weird error when instantiating a class and I am not sure if it's a bug or a feature.

I have an object defined as follows:

```
foo: {
    dataType: {
        extraData: {
            model: () => Foo,
        },
    }
}
```

Where `Foo` is a class defined elsewhere and imported. It is not possible for me to avoid the function wrapper around `Foo.

When I try to instantiate it via

```
const foo = new foo.dataType.extraData.model()(constructor_parameter);
```

it does not work saying that a class cannot be called as a function. That is understandable, but when I refactor it like

```
const model = foo.dataType.extraData.model(); 
const foo = new model(constructor_parameter);
```

it suddenly works. I am not sure if there is any difference that I have missed between the two approaches.

Comment: try wrapping `foo.dataType.extraData.model()` in parenthesis: `new (foo.dataType.extraData.model())(...);`

Comment: _"That is understandable"_ - If you understand why option 1 doesn't work, then you should also understand why your second approach works.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap `model` method call in `()` so that is resolved first as a expression and then you can use new keyword on the result of that expression which is going to be your class.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(params) {
    console.log(params)
  }
}

const foo = {
  dataType: {
    extraData: {
      model: () => Foo,
    },
  }
}


const bar = new (foo.dataType.extraData.model())(123);
```